# How to add custom if..else statements to the selected columns at a query for exporting data from database into excel file

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and [laravel-excel](https://laravel-excel.com/) for exporting some data into an Excel file.

So I added this method to the Model:

```
public static function getAccounts($id)
    {
        $records = DB::table('members')
            ->where('mys_creator_id',$id)
            ->where('mys_olp_id',4)
            ->join('my_students', 'members.mbr_usr_id', '=', 'my_students.mys_mbr_id')
            ->join('students', 'members.mbr_usr_id', '=', 'students.std_mbr_id')
            ->select('members.mbr_name', 'members.mbr_family', 'members.mbr_father_name','members.mbr_national_code','members.mbr_birthday','members.mbr_phone','members.mbr_mobile','members.mbr_post_code','members.mbr_prv_id','members.mbr_cit_id','members.mbr_gender_id','members.mbr_address','students.std_degree_id','students.std_grade_id','students.std_filed_id','students.std_major_id','students.std_school','students.std_education_type_id','my_students.mys_paid_price')
            ->get()->toArray();
        return $records;
    }
```

And this works fine but some of data holds and `id` instead of text value:

[image]

And all these ids are stored in `baseinfos` table. For example `std_degree_id` of **8** goes like this:

[image]

And now instead of returning number **8**, I need to get `bas_value` and return it in the exported Excel file.

So it would looked like this:

```
if(students.std_degree_id == 9){
     // print Elementry
}elseif(students.std_degree_id == 10){
     // print Academy
}else{
     ...
}
```

So how can I do that?

**UPDATE #1**:

```
$records = DB::table('members')
            ->where('mys_creator_id',$id)
            ->where('mys_olp_id',4)
            ->join('my_students', 'members.mbr_usr_id', '=', 'my_students.mys_mbr_id')
            ->join('students', 'members.mbr_usr_id', '=', 'students.std_mbr_id')
            ->join('baseinfos', 'students.std_degree_id', '=', 'baseinfos.bas_id')
            ->join('baseinfos', 'members.mbr_gender_id', '=', 'baseinfos.bas_id')
            ->select(...,'baseinfos.bas_value','members.mbr_address','baseinfos.bas_value',...)->get()->toArray();
    return $records;
```

If I add two more joins with `baseinfos` table, I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique
```

And this mainly because I get `baseinfos.bas_value` twice in the `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to join one more table and show the corresponding field from that table:

```
public static function getAccounts($id)
    {
        $records = DB::table('members')
            ->where('mys_creator_id',$id)
            ->where('mys_olp_id',4)
            ->join('my_students', 'members.mbr_usr_id', '=', 'my_students.mys_mbr_id')
            ->join('students', 'members.mbr_usr_id', '=', 'students.std_mbr_id')
            ->join('baseinfos', 'students.std_degree_id', '=', 'baseinfos.bas_id')
            ->select('members.mbr_name', 'members.mbr_family', 'members.mbr_father_name','members.mbr_national_code','members.mbr_birthday','members.mbr_phone','members.mbr_mobile','members.mbr_post_code','members.mbr_prv_id','members.mbr_cit_id','members.mbr_gender_id','members.mbr_address','baseinfo.bas_value','students.std_grade_id','students.std_filed_id','students.std_major_id','students.std_school','students.std_education_type_id','my_students.mys_paid_price')
            ->get()->toArray();
        return $records;
    }
```

Comment: You're right but this work if I join only one element but for more than that I get an error. I just added an **UPDATE #1** about this. Plz check it out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your update is different to what is here. You are joining `baseinfo` twice and here I listed it once. the join also seems inconsistent with one join being on `std_degree_id` and the other on `mbr_gender_id`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using getAccounts anywhere else, If you are create a new method to format this data.

```
    public static function getAccounts($id)
    {
        $degrees = [
            9 => 'Elementry',
            10 => 'Academy',
        ];

        $records = DB::table('members')
            ->where('mys_creator_id',$id)
            ->where('mys_olp_id',4)
            ->join('my_students', 'members.mbr_usr_id', '=', 'my_students.mys_mbr_id')
            ->join('students', 'members.mbr_usr_id', '=', 'students.std_mbr_id')
            ->select('members.mbr_name', 'members.mbr_family', 'members.mbr_father_name','members.mbr_national_code','members.mbr_birthday','members.mbr_phone','members.mbr_mobile','members.mbr_post_code','members.mbr_prv_id','members.mbr_cit_id','members.mbr_gender_id','members.mbr_address','students.std_degree_id','students.std_grade_id','students.std_filed_id','students.std_major_id','students.std_school','students.std_education_type_id','my_students.mys_paid_price')
            ->get();

        // if map is not working add it in collect($records)->map.
        $records->map(function($record) use($degrees) {
            $record->std_degree_id = $degrees[$record->std_degree_id];

            return $record;
        });
    
        return $records->toArray();
    }
```

But I am guessing `$record->std_degree_id` is a relation, so just use the relation title instead of the array map i created.

Comment: Undefined variable: degrees